# Cannot set colors for TMonthCalendar

Tags: delphi

I try to change settings of TMonthCalendar via CalColors but it doesn't work. Neither at design time or run time. The calendar remains unchanged.

Update:
Looks like somebody reported EXACTLY the same issue on Quality Central:
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=53494

Answer (score 7):

As David says the `TMonthCalendar` internaly uses the [`MCM_SETCOLOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb760997.aspx) message to set the colors of the control, but when the visual styles are active this message has not effect. As workaround you can use the [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  function to  disable the visual styles on this control only.

Try this sample :

```
uses
  UxTheme;

   SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar1.Handle, '', '');
   MonthCalendar1.CalColors.MonthBackColor:=clWebKhaki;
   MonthCalendar1.CalColors.TitleBackColor:=clWebDarkOrange;
```

[image]

Comment: To add to this, you want to call `SetWindowTheme` in an overridden `CreateWnd` so that the setting will be re-applied if the window handle is re-created.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is *as designed*. The control is a wrapper around the Win32 control. Take a look at the documentation for [`MCM_SETCOLOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb760997.aspx). In the remarks you find this statement.

> If visual styles are active, this message has no effect except when wParam is MCSC_BACKGROUND.

I think that in Vista and later, even attempts to set `MCSC_BACKGROUND`, which corresponds to `CalColors.BackColor`, have no effect.

If you disable visual styles in your application you can indeed see that the settings specified in `CalColors` are applied.